# error install eth-brownie by pipx because command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, brownie

I'm having problem on installing brownie for python. I've install latest python 3.9.6 and also install pipx. Any suggestion to solve this?thanks

```
PS C:\Users\dohva\Documents\Github Repo\cointoken> pipx install eth-brownie
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\dohva\\.local\\pipx\\shared\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip'' failed]' returned non-zero exit status 1.

'c:\\users\\dohva\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe -m venv --clear C:\\Users\\dohva\\.local\\pipx\\shared]' returned non-z' failed
PS C:\Users\dohva\Documents\Github Repo\cointoken> py -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
PS C:\Users\dohva\Documents\Github Repo\cointoken> pipx install eth-brownie                                                     ' failed
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\dohva\\.local\\pipx\\shared\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
                                                                                                                                ]' returned non-z
'c:\\users\\dohva\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python.exe -m venv --clear C:\\Users\\dohva\\.local\\pipx\\shared' failed
PS C:\Users\dohva\Documents\Github Repo\cointoken> brownie                                                                      ' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dohva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\brownie-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('eth-brownie==1.15.2', 'console_scripts', 'brownie')())
  File "C:\Users\dohva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\brownie-script.py", line 22, in importlib_load_entry_point    for entry_point in distribution(dist_name).entry_points
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 524, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 187, in from_name
    raise PackageNotFoundError(name)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: eth-brownie
PS C:\Users\dohva\Documents\Github Repo\cointoken>
```

Answer (score 1):

i got the same error.

make sure to install cython first

```
pip install cython
```

Then you can install brownie using pip instead of pix

```
pip install eth-brownie
```